Async requests with APIRouter or httpx.AsyncClient
I'm working on a partially developed FastAPI project. Most client requests in this project use FastAPI's built-in APIRouter with asynchronous functions for client requests, they look like this:
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession


router = APIRouter(prefix="/users", tags=["users"])

@router.get("/", response_model=list[UserResponse])
async def get_all_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 10, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    return await service_get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)

However, one existing service uses httpx for making async requests, like this:
import httpx

async def trigger_dag(dag_id: str):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, auth=(username, password))

After researching a bit I have more questions. I found that httpx supports asynchronous requests to external APIs, but I am unclear how it compares to APIRouter.

Does APIRouter not support async requests to external APIs?

What are the main differences between APIRouter and httpx, and when should you use one over the other?

Are there pros and cons when deciding one over the other?



httpx is for making http requests, APIRouter is for making api endpoints on your FastAPI app, they are used for different things

This and this should help clarify the difference between the two for you.

You are correct: APIRouter is used to define endpoints and handle incoming HTTP requests for your FastAPI app, it is not intended for making external API requests.
For (external) API calls, you use libraries like httpx instead, both synchronous and asynchronous.
